# Diameters of state spaces

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

[image]

The authors mention that if $M$ is not a factor, the diameter of $S_0(M)/Int(M)$ is equal to 2.

When $M$ is not a factor, it is easy to check that the $d(,)\leq 2$, how to check that $d(,)\geq2$?

Comment: Same comment from your other post: you're not supposed to place important information in pictures and also you really ought to try to distill this question to the essentials, not just post a picture of some paper out of context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea used by Jonathan Hole can be implemented a bit more concisely.

If $M\cap M'$ is non trivial, then it has a non-trivial projection $p$. Define $v=2p-1$. Then $v$ is a selfadjoint unitary with spectrum $\{-1,1\}$ (this is trivial to see, as $$p=1\times p + (-1)\times (1-p)$$ is the spectral decomposition).

Assuming $M\subset B(H)$, choose unit vectors $\xi,\eta\in H$ with $p\xi=\xi$, $p\eta=0$. Define
$$
\omega(x)=\langle x\xi,\xi\rangle,\qquad \phi(x)=\langle x\eta,\eta\rangle.
$$
Since $pv=p$, $(1-p)v=p-1$,
$$
\omega(v)=\langle v\xi,\xi\rangle=\langle vp\xi,\xi\rangle=\langle \xi,\xi\rangle=1,
$$
and
$$
\phi(v)=\langle v\eta,\eta\rangle=\langle v(1-p)\eta,\eta\rangle=-\langle (1-p)\eta,\eta\rangle=-1.
$$
Then, using that $v$ is central, we have for any unitary $u$ that
$$
\|\omega-u\phi u^*\|\geq|\omega(v)-\phi(uvu^*)|=|\omega(v)-\phi(v)|=1-(-1)=2.
$$

Comment: I have a question:[w] denotes the norm closure of its orbit under the action of inner $*$-automomorphism. Does it mean that if $x\in [w]$, there exists a sequence of unitaries $u_n$ such that $x=lim u_n w u_n^*$?

Comment: Yes if you are using $x$ to denote a state, which is a bit weird.

Answer (score 2):

If $M$ is not a factor then $M\cap M'\neq \mathbb{C}I$. Since the linear span of unitaries is norm-dense in any von Neumann algebra, this means there exists a unitary $u\in M\cap M'$ which is not a scalar multiple of the identity. Consider the self adjoint unitary $v=\frac{u+u^*}{2}\in M\cap M'$. Its spectrum, $\sigma(v)$, is contained in $\{-1,1\}$. We claim that in fact $\sigma(v)=\{-1,1\}$.

Indeed, if $\sigma(v)=\{-1\}$, then $\sigma(v+I)=\{0\}$, hence, since $v+I$ is self adjoint, we get $v+I=0$, i.e. $v=-I$. For all unit vectors $x$ we then obtain
$$-1=\langle -x, x\rangle=\langle vx,x\rangle=\frac{1}{2}\langle ux,x \rangle+\frac{1}{2}\langle x,ux \rangle.$$

Since $|\langle ux,x \rangle|, |\langle x,ux \rangle|\leq 1$ this is only possible if $\langle ux,x\rangle=\langle x, ux\rangle=-1$ for all unit vectors $x$ which implies that $u=-I$, which is a contradiction. Hence $\sigma(v)\neq\{-1\}$ and by a similar argument, $\sigma(v)\neq\{1\}$.

Then $\sigma(v)=\{-1,1\}$ and it is a standard fact that this set is contained in $\overline{\{\langle vx,x\rangle: \|x\|=1\}}$. Choose unit vectors $y$ and $z$ such that $\langle vy,y\rangle$ and $\langle vz,z\rangle$ approximate $1$ and $-1$, respectively. Consider the normal states $\omega=\langle \cdot y,y\rangle $ and $\phi=\langle \cdot z,z\rangle$ on $M$.

For any unitaries $u_1, u_2 \in M$ we have,
$$\|\omega \circ \text{Ad}(u_1)-\phi\circ \text{Ad}(u_2)\|\geq |\omega(u_1vu_1^*)-\phi(u_2vu_2^*)|=|\omega(v)-\phi(v)|.$$

(The last equality is due to the fact that $v$ commutes with $M$). By choosing $y$ and $z$ appropriately this last quantity can be made as close to $2$ as we wish. We conclude that $\text{diam}(S_0(M)/\text{Int}(M))\geq 2.$

Comment: Why $\sigma(v)$ is contained in $\overline{\{\langle vx,x\rangle: \|x\|=1\}}$?

Comment: Would you mind answering this question?

Comment: Claim: Let $S\in B(H)$ be self adjoint. If there exists $\alpha>0$ such that $\alpha\|x\|\leq\|Sx\|$ for all $x\in H$, then $S$ is invertible.
Proof: The inequality gives us that $S(H)$ is closed because if $Sx_n$ is Cauchy, the inequality gives us that $x_n$ is converges, hence converges to an $x$, and the continuity of $S$ implies that $Sx_n \rightarrow Sx$. In general we have $\overline{S^*(H)}=\ker S^{\perp}$. In this case, since $S$ is self adjoint and its image closed, we get $S(H)=\ker S^{\perp}=H$. Hence, $S$ is injective and surjective so the bounded inverse theorem gives us a invers

Comment: Now take any self adjoint operator $S$ and a $\lambda \in \sigma(S)$. By the contrapositive of the above claim we get a sequence of unit vectors $x_n$ such that $\|(S-\lambda I)x_n\|=0$. By Cauchy Schwarz this means that $\lim \langle (S-\lambda I)x_n, x_n\rangle=0$. Which means that $\lim \langle Tx_n, x_n\rangle=\lambda$. This means that $\lambda$ is in the closure of the set $\{\langle Sx,x \rangle\: \|x\|=1\}$.

Comment: There is a problem at the beginning of our argument. It is not true that the real part of a unitary is a unitary. In any case, you don't need all that. Just take $p$ a non-trivial projection and put $v=2p-1$. Then you immediately have that the spectrum is what you want. And you don't even need the spectrum, because you can define directly $\omega(x)=\psi(px)$, $\phi(x)=\psi((1-p)x)$ for some normal state with $\psi(p)=1$, and then evaluate at $v$.

Comment: Yes, the above $v=\frac{u+u^*}{2}$ is not unitary. Would you mind giving a correct answer?

Comment: @Martin Argerami, Would you mind answering this question?
  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3956769/calculate-the-norm-of-difference-of-two-normal-positive-linear-functionals?noredirect=1#comment8160853_3956769